# What's a good way to not work in the wrong branch?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

So you have 3 branchs of your source code (Prod, Test and Dev). The day-to-day business makes you often open 2 branchs on the same day.

**What have you found, as a trick, to differentiated your different configurations at first glance?**

I guess there are some ways to have a visual clue linked to the version you're currently working with...

*Note : This question is Visual Studio 2010 centric, but maybe you trick is cross-IDE, so maybe anybody can answer.*

Comment: Can someone migrate my question to Programmers SE, if needed instead of closing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble and end up working on the 'wrong branch' use different workspaces to help [Understanding Team Foundation Server Workspaces and Working Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Just 2 quick questions before I digg into it : Is it Eclipse specific? It available to all TFS licence versions?

Comment: Workspaces in general are a common concept to lots of IDEs but Visual studio has a number of useful workspace types/usage as per the link earlier